# Where can I ask about potential scams?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

After browsing the Internet a bit, I found a few websites (like *coin cloud miners with investment plans) that could be potential scams.

While the websites in question have a free version, the question I would want to ask would be "Is it safe to invest in (website in question)?" - in short, will I be scammed by investing in the website.

Currently, the best place I can find is [Money & Personal Finance SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/), but it's better to double-check then get a question closed for being off-topic.

Would Money SE good site for these questions? Or would another site be better?

Comment: If your question is going to be something like _Is this site safe?_ I don't think it's going to be on-topic at any SE site. Sites that answer that type of question exist out there but that's not what we're aiming for here. If I misunderstood your intended type of question, please edit and clarify.

Comment: And if you just want to ask if it is specifically on-topic for Money & Personal Finance SE, they have their own [meta](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/) where you could ask that.

Comment: @n8te I'm not a part of Money SE, so can't ask there right now. And my question would be "will I be scammed by investing in this website", not "is this website safe".

Comment: I feel pretty confident that won't be on-topic anywhere on the SE network since there's no way to provide a definitive answer. Even if they haven't scammed a single person yet, who's to say they won't one day close up shop and run off with everyone's money. No one can answer whether something like that is safe.

Comment: 15 years ago someone could have asked if Lehman Brothers was safe to invest with. Back then it would have appeared to be a perfectly safe, reputable financial firm. How'd that work out though?

Comment: We have Bitcoin.SE, Iota.SE, and Monero.SE which you might search to see if there's mention of your *-coin cloud miners and those coins. There's bound to be a question about cloud mining in general.

Comment: What about Information Security Stack Exchange? Try asking on their Meta site to see if your question is appropiate.